# ¿Cómo crear una carpeta en mi repositorio GitHub y almacenar mis códigos en esta desde el mismo Git?

Tags: git, github

Lo primero que intento hacer es crear una carpeta en mi repositorio GitHub desde Git. De tal manera que quede algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He podido hacerlo desde el mismo Github mediante la opción Add File pero aún no encuentro una forma de hacerlo desde Git.

Lo segundo es respecto a como mover/almacenar los códigos que he hecho en la carpeta que desee de mi repositorio de GitHub. Intenté hacer esto mediante el comando `git push -u origin main` pero como es de esperarse siempre los archivos locales se mueven a la raíz (main) y lo que quiero es colocarlos dentro de una carpeta (en este caso "prueba") de tal manera que quedé así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo horas buscando una solución pero aún no la encuentro :c  . Agradecería su ayuda :)

Comment: No se van a crear carpetas vacías, eso lo primero. Podrías hacer git add cuando ya haya archivos dentro de /prueba y luego podrás hacer commit y push de esos cambios.